# Mathematica Lists - Search Level Two and Return Level One?

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, pattern-matching, string-matching, levels

I need to string match in the second level of a list but have true cases returned at the first level (there's information in the first level that I need to categorize the returns).

```
 First /@ GatherBy[#, #[[3]] &] &@
  Cases[#, x_List /;
   MemberQ[x, s_String /;
    StringMatchQ[s, ("*PHYSICAL EXAMINATION*"), 
     IgnoreCase -> True]], {2}] &@
  Cases[MemoizeTable["Diagnostic_table.txt"], {_, 
   11111, __}]
```

The GatherBy command at the top is just organizing all the entries by date so I don't get any duplicates. Then I ask for cases within the diagnostic table that have terms matching the string "PHYSICAL EXAMINATION".

I have to search only the second level of the lists. If I search just the first I don't return all the true cases. If I search the first and second, I get duplicates (some cases include the desired string at both the first and second levels, so the first and second levels of the list are both returned, separately).

I need to search for the string at the second level and then return ONLY the first level of the lists that contain that matched second level. I don't need to exclude the second level, I just don't want it returned separately like it is if I search levels one and two.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: For example, if I were searching the list {a,b,c,{x,y},d,x} for "x" on the second level, the function above would give me {x,y}. What I WANT is for it to give me {a,b,c,{x,y},d,x}.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?

```
list = {{a, b, c, {x, y}, d, x}, {a, b, c, d, x}, {{a, b, c, d}, x}}

Select[list, MemberQ[#, x, {2}] &]
```

Output:

{{a, b, c, {x, y}, d, x}}

**Update**

This will also work

```
Cases[list, _?(MemberQ[#, x, {2}] &)]
```

---

**Update to @rose question (see comments)**

Given the following data how can I select for entries which contain the words "PHYSICAL EXAMINATION" within a string, for example within the string "P-023 PHYSICAL EXAMINATION, TECHNICIAN, NOS", at the second level (ie only within the sublist)? (I have modified @rose's example somewhat)

```
rdata2={{1111113,21119,SQLDateTime[{2011,1,11,11,11,0.`}],31111,"EB/JW",1,47000,"T-510 CHEEK",{"T-510 CHEEK","No Examination, NOS"},"Text bla bla bla physical examination bla bla"},{1111114,21119,SQLDateTime[{2011,2,11,11,11,0.`}],31112,"EB/JW",1,47000,"T-510 CHEEK",{"T-510 CHEEK","P-023 PHYSICAL EXAMINATION, TECHNICIAN, NOS"},"Text bla bla bla"},
{1111115,21000,SQLDateTime[{2011,1,11,11,11,0.`}],31111,"EB/JW",1,47000,"T-510 CHEEK",{"T-510 CHEEK","P-023 physical examination, TECHNICIAN, NOS"},"Text bla bla bla physical examination bla bla"}};
```

(1) One way  (returning only entry 1111114)

```
Select[rdata2, 
 MemberQ[Characters@#, 
   Flatten@{___, Characters["PHYSICAL EXAMINATION"], ___}, {2}] &]
```

(2) Ignore case (but still selecting within sublist)

```
Select[rdata2,MemberQ[ToLowerCase@Characters@#,
Flatten@{___,ToLowerCase@
Characters["PHYSICAL EXAMINATION"],___},{2}]&]
```

(selects for entries 1111114 & 1111115)

(3) A final example (select for entries with "No Examination" within sublist but where there may be *zero or more* characters between "No" and "Examination", and where case is again ignored)

```
Select[rdata2, 
 MemberQ[ToLowerCase@Characters@#, 
   Flatten@Riffle[
     ToLowerCase@Characters@{"No", "Examination"}, ___, {1, -1, 
      2}], {2}] &]
```

(selects for entry 1111113)

There are no doubt more efficient ways to proceed. I hope I have interpreted the question correctly.

Comment: That looks about like what I what, I'll play around with it and see if it integrates properly with all my other stuff and then vote up your answer, hopefully! Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... so, I tried `list = Cases[
  MemoizeTable["MasterDiagnostic_table.txt"], {_, 25749, __}]`

Comment: (Oops) and `Select[list, MemberQ[#, "*PHYSICAL EXAMINATION*", {2}] &]` but it doesn't return anything. It should be returning five things. Is it because it's a string?

Comment: Here's an example of one of the lists I'm searching in: `{{1111113, 21119, SQLDateTime[{2011, 1, 11, 11, 11, 0.}], 31111, 
  "EB/JW", 1, 047000, 
  "T-510 CHEEK", {"T-510 CHEEK", 
   "P-023 PHYSICAL EXAMINATION, TECHNICIAN, NOS"}, 
  "Text bla bla bla physical examination bla bla"},{1111114, 21119, SQLDateTime[{2011, 2, 11, 11, 11, 0.}], 31112, 
  "EB/JW", 1, 047000, 
  "T-510 CHEEK", {"T-510 CHEEK", 
   "P-023 PHYSICAL EXAMINATION, TECHNICIAN, NOS"}, 
  "Text bla bla bla"}}`

Comment: Searching on the first level of the list I only return the first entry, where `"physical examination"` is found in the text at the end of the entry. I wouldn't get the second entry, where it's "hidden" in a second inner list.

Comment: It doesn't return anything (at least on levels one through three) when I run the code you wrote, so I'm thinking it has to have something to do with the structure or head of my data.

Comment: @Rose. See update to answer.  I hope this is nearer to what you want?

Comment: @Rose. `Select[rdata2, MemberQ[#,"P-023 PHYSICAL EXAMINATION, TECHNICIAN, NOS",{2}]&]` will also work, of course (but not what you want?)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements, you may consider:

```
dat = {{1111113, 21119, SQLDateTime[{2011, 1, 11, 11, 11, 0.`}], 
    31111, "EB/JW", 1, 47000, 
    "T-510 CHEEK", {"T-510 CHEEK", "No Examination, NOS"}, 
    "Text bla bla bla physical examination bla bla"}, {1111114, 21119,
     SQLDateTime[{2011, 2, 11, 11, 11, 0.`}], 31112, "EB/JW", 1, 
    47000, "T-510 CHEEK", {"T-510 CHEEK", 
     "P-023 PHYSICAL EXAMINATION, TECHNICIAN, NOS"}, 
    "Text bla bla bla"}, {1111115, 21000, 
    SQLDateTime[{2011, 1, 11, 11, 11, 0.`}], 31111, "EB/JW", 1, 47000,
     "T-510 CHEEK", {"T-510 CHEEK", 
     "P-023 physical examination, TECHNICIAN, NOS"}, 
    "Text bla bla bla physical examination bla bla"}};

p = 
 Position[ dat,
   _String?(StringMatchQ[#, "*PHYSICAL EXAMINATION*", IgnoreCase -> True] &),
   {2, 3}
 ];

dat[[ Union[First /@ p] ]]
```